# video component doesn't display video (displays white screen)

Tags: angularjs, video, angular-components

I am building a custom video component with angular, and am passing in sources externally. When not using the component, the video displays well. When using the component, even though I can see that the sources did successfully get passed in (via inspect element), the video doesn't display. I have a feeling that this relates somehow to the lifecycle.

Code:

home page:

```
<customvideo srcs="video.srcs"></customvideo>
```

(video.srcs is a list of src urls and mimetypes)

component:

```
angular.module('home.app').component('customvideo', {
templateUrl: ['config', function(config) {
    return config.TEMPLATES_URL + 'customvideo.template.html';
}],
bindings: {
    srcs: '<'
},
controller: ['config','UserRest', 'CultureRest', 'tSpaceRest', function HomeController(config, UserRest, CultureRest, tSpaceRest) {
    var vm = this;

}]
})
```

And finally the template:

```
<video class="full-video">
<source ng-repeat="src in $ctrl.srcs" ng-src="{{src.url | trustUrl}}" type="{{src.mimeType}}"/>
</video>
```

Edit: The problem is not actually with the REST call as I had thought. Manually inserting a source into the component still did not show the video. I will have to look and try to decipher how mine and Mathieu's differ

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, I give you my plunker for try it https://plnkr.co/edit/7afE9xFJ15JENgwmEmGY?p=preview

Comment: Hey mathieu, I edited the post with important info that I think is the difference (my sources are being pulled from a restful call). I simulated a restful call in your plunker by adding a timeout before the srcs are loaded, and the video never shows up now. Thank you, that is an important clarification to make https://plnkr.co/edit/ER9eOUOfgMqx0Y9T1KY8?p=preview

Comment: Above comment is incorrect, or at least the REST call is not the problem (can look at the edit)

Answer (score 0):

So my answer had nothing to do with loading time or dependencies. The problem was simply that when I changed the video, I had forgotten to include the 'controls preload' options in the video...